# thread safety of a class imported from dll

Tags: c++, dll, thread-safety, shared-libraries

I have a dll which exports the interface

```
class Qwe{
    virtual void a() = 0;
    virtual void b() = 0;
};

extern "C" Qwe* createQwe();
```

I load it in my program and create multiple Qwe objects. The question is whether accessing those objects from different threads is safe? Shall I open the new library instance for each object, or one is enough?

No static data members are used, and library functions are not thread-safe by themselves.

To define the question better... exported class may look like this

```
class QweImpl : public Qwe{
   public:
      virtual void a() {
          std::fill(data.begin(), data.end(), 1.0)};
   private:
      std::vector<double> data; };
```

is QweImpl::a() safe here? In the sense that two different QweImpl objects can simultaneously call their a() functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows you can only load a library once. Further attempts to load a library only increments a reference counter. So therefore 'loading a library for each object' is a non-starter.

If your Qwe class contains data members or fields, which I can't tell if it does or not, than you could protect access to shared memory using critical sections (or some other mechanism) inside of Qwe.

Comment: Qwe does not have any data, its implementations surely do. To be precise, the exported class

    class QweImpl : public Qwe{
       public:
          virtual void a(){
              std::fill(data.begin(), data.end(), 1.0); };
       private:
          std::vector<double> data; 
    };

needs to take care about thread-safety itself within a() function?

Comment: sorry for the mess I failed to enter the code into the comment, is it possible here at all?

Comment: If you expect that multiple threads will be accessing one particular QweImple instance than no it is not thread safe. You will need a critical section to make sure writing to data is safe.

Answer (score 1):

If the class has members that can be accessed across multiple threads then you will have to use a synchronization mechanism to control access.